# How to edit bars styles to the following figure?

Tags: matlab, plot

How I can edit the bars, so that it appears as the following picture with the grid.

[image]

```
   x=[4:4:48]; 
      y=[25.312399   1.81357174   ;
 9.3078819    1.47970432 ; 
 7.66729673    1.26972206  ;
  6.96170053  1.17688473 ;
6.77668306   1.2387898;
6.0174443   1.26357444;
5.59616954  0.95115584;
5.2694634    1.041687;
5.1104946    1.02342079 ;
4.917285     0.8655728 ;
 4.7892952    0.85538917;
 4.7373291      0.91927867 ]
 bar(x,y);
  xlabel('Check size (s)')

   ylabel('Computaion Costs (s)')
```

Comment: What is `x`?  I don't see it defined.  If I copy and paste your code into MATLAB it asks the same question.  Did you mean `bar(y(:,1),y(:,2))`?

Comment: sorry, here is   x=[4:4:48];

Comment: Thanks!  Can you [edit] the question to include `x` so others will find it in the question (instead of being buried in the comments)?

Comment: I did it. sorry for that

Comment: If you want to recreate the hatch pattern as well, see [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2011/07/15/creating-hatched-patches/)

Answer (score 2):

You can access Axes object and set the `YGrid` properties `'on'`.

```
x=[4:4:48]; 
y=[25.312399   1.81357174   ;
 9.3078819    1.47970432 ; 
 7.66729673    1.26972206  ;
  6.96170053  1.17688473 ;
6.77668306   1.2387898;
6.0174443   1.26357444;
5.59616954  0.95115584;
5.2694634    1.041687;
5.1104946    1.02342079 ;
4.917285     0.8655728 ;
 4.7892952    0.85538917;
 4.7373291      0.91927867 ]
bar(x,y);
xlabel('Check size (s)')
ylabel('Computaion Costs (s)')

ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';
```

Output:
[image]

If you also want to add minor ticks and minor grib as shown in your example figure, you can add the following additional code:

```
ax.YMinorTick = 'on';
ax.YMinorGrid = 'on';
```

Output:
[image]

Update: The bar color and linewidth is also changed to match your example figure

```
bar(x,y,'FaceColor',[0.447, 0.945, 0.302],'LineWidth',2);
xlabel('Check size (s)')
ylabel('Computaion Costs (s)')
ax = gca;
ax.YGrid = 'on';

ax.YMinorTick = 'on';
ax.YMinorGrid = 'on';
```

[image]

Comment: Bah! Excel-style figures are so ugly! :)

Comment: @Banghua , it is not made by matlab

Comment: @Mohamed You want to make a Excel-style figure with Matlab?

Comment: I need to make the bars to appear like the picture attached in the question. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Mohamed What is missing in my answer?

Comment: the style of bars. if you see the attached picture, u can notice that the bars is not solid, it has a different style which is really good. Thanks again for your help

Comment: do u see lines inside each bar? There are inside lines that make the bar looks better. I really appreciate your answer. But take a look at the bar's style

Comment: @Mohamed: the horizontal grid lines are ugly, and the hatch pattern is even worse. All experts in graphing will tell you not to use hatch patterns, they were useful back in the days of low-res dot matrix printers, but now just cause problems when photocopying and induce headaches in readers. Don’t use hatch patterns please!!!

Comment: but I found that picture in an academic paper published in a very good place. I thought it looks efficient than using straightforward bars

Comment: @CrisLuengo I can't agree more. The horizontal grid lines always remind me the Excel-style figures :)

Comment: @Mohamed: Sadly, most academics are clueless about making effective graphs, and that includes the folk publishing in fancy journals. I recommend you read “The Visual Display of Quantitative Information” by Edward Tufte, or really any of his other books, if you want to learn what to pay attention to when making graphs. He’ll really open up your eyes. He’s fantastic!

Comment: @Mohamed, I agree wholeheartedly with ChrisLuengo.  Simple, clean, intuitive graphics are the best communicators. I've read 8+ books on data visualization and presentation techniques and ChrisLuengo's advice is spot-on.